# Material-UI NativeSelect preselected option not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, material-ui

I've this code here:

```
<NativeSelect
classes={{
    icon: classes.icon
}}
className={classes.select}
onChange={this.onVersionChange}
    >
    {
        Object.keys(interface_versions).map(key => {
            return <option key={key} value={key}
            title={key}
            className={classes.selectOption}
            {...urlParams.get('ifversion') == key ? 'selected' : ''}
        >
            {key}
        </option>
        })};
</NativeSelect>
```

I've tried now to preselect an option during the creation if the key matches my URL parameter value but it's not working. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Hi, maybe you can put your code on https://codesandbox.io/s/new to better understanding your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the selected option by adding a `value` property to the `NativeSelect` component.

Something like this:

```
<NativeSelect 
  ....
  value={urlParams.get('ifversion')}
  ....
/>
  .....
</NativeSelect>
```

Comment: You didn't understand me. I need to preselect the select option. I already have my options. Normally in HTML you can add selected to the option to preselect it but in this case it don't works and I don't know why,.

Comment: @Mr.Jo By using the `value` property you can set which `<option>` is selected. It has the same effect as adding the `selected` property to an `<option>` element.

Comment: Now I understand. Stupid me. Thanks a lot mate!